# @ModelAttribute method handles @RequestBody object throws HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, modelattribute

In @ControllerAdvice class, I just want get request body. I have no idea better than handle it inside a @ModelAttribute method and set @RequestBody value into props. So, problem here is when I open @RequestBody it still get request body as expected, but after that it throws HttpMessageNotReadableException.
Someone can tell me the reason and have idea to resolve problem. It really means to me.

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{


    public CustomRestExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    private Object request;

    @ModelAttribute
    public void setRequest(@RequestBody Object request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(this.request)
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm stuck at the same problem :(

Comment: I'm so sorry. It's really long time ago. Maybe, because I couldn't solve this issue, so I didn't get the request value anymore.

https://github.com/zcmgyu/it-blog-backend/blob/7fe50c690647e2785111993983c70b11b7a2f93c/src/main/java/com/aptech/itblog/controller/CustomRestExceptionHandler.java

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you are getting HttpMessageNotReadableException is because you are trying to map JSON to an object using @RequestBody annotation twice. First in the ControllerAdvice model attribute then in the controller method parameter. Assuming you have a controller which looks like this

```
@RestController
public class MyController{

@PostMapping("endpoint")
public Response processRequest(@RequestBody MyObject myRequest)
System.out.println("bla bla");
}
```

Try removing the @RequestBody annotation and change it to

```
@PostMapping("endpoint")
public Response processRequest(final MyObject myRequest)
System.out.println("bla bla");
}
```

Then modify you Controller Advice to look like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{


    public CustomRestExceptionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    private MyObject request;



@ModelAttribute("myRequest") //same as in controller
    public MyObject setRequest(@RequestBody MyObject request) {
        this.request = request;
        return request;
    }

    @Override protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(this.request)
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Your ModelAttribute now returns the converted object so it can be passed on to the controller. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because it is a really long time ago, so I could not verify this bug anymore. If your answer could anybody here, I will mark your answer. Thank again.